# Button event not firing when wrapped in a jquery popup

Tags: asp.net, jquery, vb.net, popup

I have a form in a page that is popped up using the jquery dialog thus:
using jquery ui 1.8.9 and jquery 1.4.4

```
//a button fires this
    $("#AppointmentDialog").dialog("open");

<div id="AppointmentDialog">
    <h3 runat="server" id="h3Title"></h3>
    <table cellpadding="5">

<!-- form -->
    <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><asp:Button runat="server" ID="butMove" Text="Move Appointment" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

this is using manky old asp vb .net 2.0 (arghh)
so you arent seeing onclick= on the butMoveAppointment but there is this in the code behind

```
Protected Sub butMoveAppointment_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles butMove.Click
    'do stuff
End Sub
```

so this div dialogs up on a button click, but when i try to submit this popped up form with the 
clicking the butMove appointment just does nothing at all
if i move it out of the popup it does fire
is this because the popup doesnt simply show and centre the styled div?
presumably i can get around this somehow?

thanks

nat

Comment: Where is your jQuery that pops it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that that pop up modifies DOM. It takes that div out of DOM. What I usually used to do is just put dummy button in your pop-up, leave the event handling outside of the popup, and then just handle onclick in pop up via jquery and forward it to the one in the form (trigger click event from the jquery).

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any jQuery here, but my guess is that your button is not being handled "live". So if you are propogating your pop-up after page load, the event handler won't attach to it. jQuery has a method that allows for post-pageload handlers:

http://api.jquery.com/live/